# JUnit assertion to find colour of css element and assert if it is expected colour or not

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How do i do an assert statement in my selenium tests where i need to find the element(we have multiple instances of that element)
then find the colour of element and assert if it is expected or not?

was trying something like

```
assertThat(webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("class").contains(".accepted")) && By.cssSelector("color").equals("green"));
```

As i need to assert for a classname and color of the element

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, it is a two-step process. First grab all the elements that you want to assess, then test them for the cssValue you want.

If, for instance, you wanted to get all the links on Yahoo!'s home page and discover which ones aren't their standard blue color (rgba (50, 79, 225, 1)), you'd use something like the following: (System.outs so you could better see what's happening when your run this on your page):

```
   String YAHOO_BLUE_LINK_COLOR = "rgba(50, 79, 225, 1)";

   //get all the links on the page
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement currentLink: links){

        try{
            //get the cssValue "color" for each and see if it contains the color
            assertTrue(currentLink.getCssValue("color").contains(YAHOO_BLUE_LINK_COLOR));
            System.out.println("Link:" + currentLink.getText() + " IS blue.");
        }catch(AssertionError e){
            System.out.println("Link:" + currentLink.getText() + " is NOT blue");
        }
    }
```